QML - Sort a TableModel using Python backend
In a Qt 6.8 project using QML for the frontend and Python for the backend, I am trying to implement a TableModel/ListModel filter system. I read the documentation of QSortFilterProxyModel, but I didn't find a working example in Python.
How could I modify the simplified code below to integrate a model filter method via my application’s backend and link it to my search bar?
Here is my current code:
main.py:
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from PySide6.QtCore import QtMsgType, qInstallMessageHandler
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

def handle_qml_message(msg_type, context, message):
    print(f"QML: {message}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    qInstallMessageHandler(handle_qml_message)

    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    qml_file = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "main.qml"
    engine.load(qml_file)
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec())


main.qml:
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    TextField {
        id: textField
        anchors {
            top: parent.top
            left: parent.left
        }
        width: 300
        height: 30
        placeholderText: "Search ..."
        onTextChanged: print(text)
    }

    HorizontalHeaderView {
        id: horizontalHeader
        z: 2
        syncView: tableView
        anchors {
            top: textField.bottom
            left: parent.left
        }
        resizableColumns: false
        model: ["Name", "Color"]
        delegate: Rectangle {
            implicitHeight: 50
            implicitWidth: 50
            color: "lightblue"

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: modelData
            }
        }
    }

    TableView {
        id: tableView
        anchors {
            top: horizontalHeader.bottom
            bottom: parent.bottom
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
        }
        columnSpacing: 1
        rowSpacing: 1
        clip: true

        model: TableModel {
            TableModelColumn { display: "name" }
            TableModelColumn { display: "color" }

            rows: [
                { "name": "cat", "color": "black" },
                { "name": "dog", "color": "brown" },
                { "name": "bird", "color": "white" },
                { "name": "fish", "color": "blue" },
                { "name": "rabbit", "color": "gray" },
                { "name": "horse", "color": "brown" },
                { "name": "snake", "color": "green" },
                { "name": "hamster", "color": "golden" },
                { "name": "turtle", "color": "green" },
                { "name": "parrot", "color": "red" },
                { "name": "frog", "color": "green" },
                { "name": "lizard", "color": "brown" },
                { "name": "butterfly", "color": "multicolor" },
                { "name": "bee", "color": "yellow" },
                { "name": "sheep", "color": "white" },
                { "name": "goat", "color": "black" },
                { "name": "pig", "color": "pink" },
                { "name": "cow", "color": "black and white" },
                { "name": "duck", "color": "yellow" },
                { "name": "swan", "color": "white" },
                { "name": "eagle", "color": "brown" },
                { "name": "owl", "color": "gray" },
                { "name": "peacock", "color": "blue and green" },
                { "name": "deer", "color": "brown" },
                { "name": "bear", "color": "dark brown" },
                { "name": "wolf", "color": "gray" },
                { "name": "fox", "color": "orange" },
                { "name": "lion", "color": "golden" },
                { "name": "tiger", "color": "orange with stripes" },
                { "name": "elephant", "color": "gray" }
            ]
        }

        delegate: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 100
            implicitHeight: 50
            border.width: 1

            Text {
                text: display
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }
}


A quick search turned up this question that provides an example. It's Qt5, but it should be mostly the same. The important thing though is that QSortFilterProxyModel works on QAbstractItemModels, not models defined directly in QML.

@JarMan TableModel and ListModel both derive QAbstractItemModel, so a QSortFilterProxyModel workw ith them.

@Grecko ok, good to know that it works. It's still much more common to have the model defined in the backend.

This post provided me a simple example of how to make it work : stackoverflow.com/q/34252413/11603485
Like @JarMan mentioned , it is not possible to declare the model in the QML file, it should be instantiated in the python file. Thanks for your help !
